# How do you edit the video by lowering the quality and then uploading it again using Premiere Pro like this video?

Tags: premiere

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/cXGA9wAMuSY

I want to edit it like this video, but I want to know how to edit it by lowering the quality and then raising it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an effect known as Data Moshing - here's how to do it in After Effects:
https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/datamoshing-make-footage-look-trippy/